# Remove standard deviation from legend ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I would like to remove sd bars and mean from legend while keeping them on the main figure. In my case I have this:

[image: Image with sd and mean]

And I want something like this:
[image]

This is my code:

```
data_summary <- function(x) {
    m <- mean(x)
    ymin <- m-std.error(x)
    ymax <- m+std.error(x)
    return(c(y=m,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax))
  }
a<-ggplot(esto,aes(x= Group, y=value,  colour = Group, fill=fluency_test),
         pattern_fill = "black",
         colour  = 'black') +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA,lwd=1.5) +
    guides(colour = "none")+
    geom_point(position=position_jitterdodge(),alpha=0.5)+
    xlab("Group")+
    labs(y = names(features)[[i_feature]])+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
    stat_summary(fun.data=data_summary, color="black",position=position_dodge(width=0.75), size = 1.3)+
    scale_shape_manual("Summary Statistics", values=c("Mean"="+"))+
    scale_color_manual(values=c("#7CAE00","#F8766D","#00BFC4","#C77CFF"))+
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("white","azure3"))+
    theme_gray(base_size = 18)+
    theme(legend.key.size = unit(2, "cm"),
          legend.key.width = unit(1,"cm"),legend.title=element_blank(),panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the point range from being displayed in the legend by adding `show.legend=FALSE` to `stat_summary`.

Using a minimal reprex based on  `mtcars`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(color = "black", show.legend = FALSE)
#> No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
```

[image]